# Android 6.0 don't see beacon

Tags: android, ibeacon, beacon

I have android 6.0 phone. This app doesn't see the beacon. [I am getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1KhO.png)

```
I / BluetoothLeScanner: startRegisteration: mLeScanClients = {org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop $ 4 @ 5445b45 = android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner $ BleScanCallbackWrapper @ d9ce5fa}.
```

Can you help me?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BeaconConsumer {
private BeaconManager beaconManager;
private Beacon nearestBeacon;

private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
private static final String TAG = "Beacon";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    beaconManager=BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(20));
    beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10));
    beaconManager.bind(this);



    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    if(this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("This app needs location acces");

        builder.setMessage("Please grant location..");
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,null);
        builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
           requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
            }
        });
        builder.show();

    }
}
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d(TAG, "coarse location permission granted");
            } else {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Functionality limited");
                builder.setMessage("Since location access has not been granted, this app will not be able to discover beacons when in the background.");
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    }

                });
                builder.show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    beaconManager.unbind(this);
}

@Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> collection, Region region) {
            if(collection.size()>0){
                Log.d(TAG,collection.toString());
                List beaconList=new ArrayList(collection);

            }
        }
    });
    try {
        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueID",null,null,null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public void getNearestBeacon(List beaconList) {
    for(int i=0; i<beaconList.size(); i++)
    {
        Beacon tempBeacon=((Beacon) beaconList.get(i));
        if(tempBeacon.getId3() != nearestBeacon.getId3())
        {
            if(tempBeacon.getDistance() < nearestBeacon.getDistance())
            {
                nearestBeacon=tempBeacon;
            }
        }
    }
    // t1.setText(nearestBeacon.getId2().toString());
    Log.d(TAG,"Beacon'ın Majoru: " + nearestBeacon.getId2());


}
}
```

> My application codes.

Comment: I know from a thread on a different forum that your question specifically is about the Android Beacon Library, so you should probably say so in your question.   That log line doesn't indicate anything is wrong, so we'll need more information to help you.  Can you detect the beacon with an off the shelf transmitter like Locate?  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en

Comment: You submit in the application that detects beacons but my application doesnt see.

Comment: http://i.hizliresim.com/QvZA1Z.png detected.

Comment: When you run your code, what lines do you see in LogCat?

Comment: try {
        
public void getNearestBeacon(List beaconList) {
    for(int i=0; i<beaconList.size(); i++)
    {
        Beacon tempBeacon=((Beacon) beaconList.get(i));
        if(tempBeacon.getId3() != nearestBeacon.getId3())
        {
            if(tempBeacon.getDistance() < nearestBeacon.getDistance())
            {
                nearestBeacon=tempBeacon;
            }
        }
    }
    // t1.setText(nearestBeacon.getId2().toString());
    Log.d(TAG,"Beacon'ın Majoru: " + nearestBeacon.getId2());


}
}

Comment: In this application location of LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is going wrong for your application, but for scanning on Android 6, it's important that:

- bluetooth is on
- location is on
- location permission granted

Are you scanning for iBeacons? In that case, you can try this library: https://github.com/inthepocket/ibeacon-scanner-android to see if you have more luck.